# Postfix configuration Error, Status=dereffered... But where?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

```
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated     defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = localhost.localdomain
myorigin = localhost.localdomain
mydestination = 
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1
default_transport = smtp    
relay_transport = relay
inet_protocols = all
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail
```

So the problem is, it tells me now there is a configuration error. And when I try to send a mail, it also tells me:

```
status=bounced (mail for localhost loops back to myself)
```

Full log:

```
Aug  2 13:00:20 imapaka-01 postfix/smtpd[15528]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Aug  2 13:00:37 imapaka-01 postfix/smtpd[15528]: improper command pipelining after EHLO from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]: mail from: root@localhost\r\nrcpt to: test@localhost.localdomain\r\ndata\r\nSubject:Testnachricht\r\n\r
Aug  2 13:00:37 imapaka-01 postfix/smtpd[15528]: 53B5A625269: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Aug  2 13:00:37 imapaka-01 postfix/cleanup[15532]: 53B5A625269: message-id=<20170802110037.53B5A625269@localhost.localdomain>
Aug  2 13:00:37 imapaka-01 postfix/qmgr[15523]: 53B5A625269: from=<root@localhost>, size=395, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug  2 13:00:37 imapaka-01 postfix/smtp[15534]: 53B5A625269: to=<test@localhost>, orig_to=<test@localhost.localdomain>, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for localhost loops back to myself)
Aug  2 13:00:37 imapaka-01 postfix/cleanup[15532]: 607A662526B: message-id=<20170802110037.607A662526B@localhost.localdomain>
Aug  2 13:00:37 imapaka-01 postfix/bounce[15535]: 53B5A625269: sender non-delivery notification: 607A662526B
Aug  2 13:00:37 imapaka-01 postfix/qmgr[15523]: 607A662526B: from=<>, size=2423, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Aug  2 13:00:37 imapaka-01 postfix/qmgr[15523]: 53B5A625269: removed
Aug  2 13:00:37 imapaka-01 postfix/smtp[15534]: 607A662526B: to=<root@localhost>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.02/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for localhost loops back to myself)
Aug  2 13:00:37 imapaka-01 postfix/qmgr[15523]: 607A662526B: removed
Aug  2 13:00:38 imapaka-01 postfix/smtpd[15528]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
```

Comment: setting mydestination to nothing with `mydestination = ` is the culprit. why are you doing that?   try something like `mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Answering from the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383432/postfix-configuration-error-status-dereffered-but-where#comment681694_383432):

> setting mydestination to nothing with `mydestination =` is the culprit. Why are you doing that? Try something like `mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost` instead. – cas Aug 2 at 12:48